# Team Explorer 2008 - using on a Macintosh

Tags: macos, team-explorer

We use Team Foundation 2008, but we now have Macintosh machines on our network.  We use Team Explorer 2008 on our Windows machines, but I can't find an installation for TE 2008 for the Macintosh.  Is it advisable to install Team Explorer 2010 on the Macintosh connecting to the TFS 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't Team Explorer for Mac. You could try [Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990%28VS.90%29.aspx).